# Design an alarm system based on logs in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, alarm

How would you design a system which can generate alarms based on certain conditions on data stored on Elasticsearch?

I'm thinking of a system similar to AWS CloudWatch.

Proposed alarming system should be able to work under following conditions:

1. There could be thousands of users using this system to create alarms.
2. There could be thousands of alarms active at any given time.
3. Shouldn't have high impact on query performance.
4. Large volume of data.

Naive approach would be to apply all the alarm conditions when a new record is added to Elasticsearch or a service/lambda function executing all the alarm rules at a specified time interval but I really doubt a system like this can satisfy above all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in learning more about the Alerts feature in X-Pack.  It includes Watchers, which are essentially the query you want to monitor.

> Take control of your alerts by viewing, creating, and managing all of
>   them from a single UI. Stay in the know with real-time updates on
>   which alerts are running and what actions were taken.

Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/xpack-alerting.html

Sales Page: https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/alerting

Comment: Thanks @EricPSU for the info. In case you have more info 1. What performance impact does it have on query performance? We use AWS managed Elasticsearch service. I have to check how difficult it would be for us to get them installed this plugin.

Comment: @Abhijeet - Since it is functionality built by Elasticsearch, I wouldn't expect any performance decrease based on using the Alerts feature.  I also expect AWS to support X-Pack, its a very common add-on for Elasticsearch.

Comment: Looks like X-Pack is not supported by AWS Elasticsearch. Correct me if I'm wrong. This plugin will only allow users to create alarms by using Kibana. But we want to expose another service/frontend which will help users to create alarms instead of playing with Kibana dashboard directly.

Comment: Alarms can be created and viewed in Kibana, but that is not the only interface.  Everything done in Elastic is based on a RESTful API, so your custom UI could just interact with the same RESTful API that Kibana uses.  I'd be surprised if X-Pack was not support by AWS, you should submit a support ticket to verify.  Post the response for the benefit of the group.